# Should we break the [circuit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

In the DIY.SE folksonomy, the electrical specialty's tags stand out as a cross-connected pile of confusion, and one of the chief culprits is [circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit).  <s>While not particularly rare (129 questions use it), a quick glance at the first few dozen questions using it reveals only a few that could be routed to an electrical expert by way of [circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit) -- most of the time, it's used in a redundant fashion with [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical), [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring), or another tag in the electrical specialty.</s>It's gone now.

Should we burninate this tag for how little value it provides? Synonymize it with say [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring) and migrate questions using it otherwise off of it?  Or leave it alone for now and check back later to see if it's grown as a problem?

Comment: According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/diy/query/583502/single-tag-questions?TagName=circuit) we have 11 questions who use [circuit] as their only tag, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think [circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit) is a very useful tag, as I can't think of any time you'd use it as the only tag on a post.  I also don't think many folks would use it to find questions they might be interested in.

The tag should probably be removed.