# Time to redistribute [electrical-distribution]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

As I noted [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/should-we-break-the-circuit), the electrical specialty tags on DIY.SE are a mess.  While that thread already addresses one of the chief culprits, namely [circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit), another tag of confusion lurks in the mud: [electrical-distribution](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-distribution), used by 82 questions.  Again, like [circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit), it adds very little value to a question over [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical), or another, more specialized electrical specialty tag such as [electrical-panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-panel) or [circuit-breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-breaker); however, it is more commonly seen standalone (5 questions out of the first 15 use it in a standalone fashion).  Is this another burnination or synonymization candidate, perhaps with [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical)?

Comment: I think when it started, the tag was for questions that had to do with the electrical system beyond the service drop. Transformers, types of systems, etc.  However, it's likely not used properly, and can probably be killed.

Comment: According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/diy/query/583503/single-tag-questions?TagName=electrical-distribution), we have 16 questions whose only tag is [electrical-distribution].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when it started, the tag was for questions that had to do with the electrical system beyond the service drop. Transformers, types of systems, etc. However, it's likely not used properly, and can probably be killed.

The tag can be removed from any questions that are not asking about the distribution of electricity.

Comment: Seems like creating guidance for the tag and removing it from the inappropriate ones would be the way to go. Is it about the "far" (utility) side of the drop, or on-premises distribution? For example out buildings and sub-panels?

Comment: @dlu to me, "electrical distribution" deals with anything before, and including the local transformer.   Maybe the drop to the meter, but that's it.  Using a transformer to supply outbuildings, could also be on topic for that tag