# Should we remove the [wire]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

As I noted [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/should-we-break-the-circuit) and [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/time-to-redistribute-electrical-distribution), the DIY.SE electrical folksonomy is in serious need of cleanup.  While a couple of the minor tagging errors, such as [ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground), are small enough that I can handle the editing myself, we have 109 questions that use [wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire).  Once again, this tag adds very little value over the tags it is seen with, such as [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical), [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring), and [thermostat-c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat-c-wire).

So, should we burninate it altogether, or synonymize it with [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring)?  Or does it provide value in some context I am not aware of?

Comment: P.S. as per [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/diy/query/583503/single-tag-questions?TagName=wire), there are a mere 11 questions that use [wire] as their only tag.  (This needs to be taken with a grain of salt though, as there are a few appliance-wiring questions that are tagged  [oven] [wire] or equivalent.)

Comment: I'm surprised there's no proper [burninate tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) here

Answer (score 3):

[wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire) is only a good tag on questions that ask specifically about wire.  For example: "Is there a difference between stranded and solid wire?", "What material is the insulation of THHN wire?", etc.

If questions are tagged with the [wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire) tag, but are not discussing wire. Then that tag should be removed from the post.

Comment: This is good, but we should also address [tag:wiring] then as well (having both is confusing). A quick glance through shows that [tag:electrical] and [tag:wiring] are often used for the same purpose: "What size wire should I use?" "How do I wire this ceiling fan to be controlled by this switch?" -- perhaps we can drop [tag:wiring] and use either [tag:wire] (for questions about wire, specifically) or [tag:electrical] (for questions about connecting fixtures, circuits, etc)?

Comment: FYI -- I suggested [wire] as a synonym for [wiring].  Let me know if that's not a workable solution.